# Worklight Push notification in app without authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement the push notification feature for a Worklight application. 
In the Push docs it is stated that the app should use authentication, also the sample project contains a login form used in this purpose. The problem is that my app does not require any authentication and/or login. I have the PushAdapter successfully deployed, also the required client code but I cannot get the client registered in the WL's Push notification console.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is required for Worklight Push.  Your Push adapter is going to use userid to find the device to push to.  This wouldn't make any sense if the mobile device didn't authenticate with *some* user id.

Comment: Ok, I understand this. But is there any way to do the subscription to the push adapter without using a login form? I have tried to use a dummy login request with the following code:pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.login = function () {
    var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
    var options = {};
    options.parameters = {
        j_username : device.uuid,
        j_password : "somepass"
    };
    but of course that I get a server error: Authentication did not succeed for user ID b87c917e9f0f1zzz. An invalid user ID or password was specified.

Comment: use the SampleAppRealm (or any realm that uses the com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule Login Module)

Comment: And do I still need to have the above type of "dummy" authentication?

Comment: Something like: <realm loginModule="MYMobileAppLoginModule" name="MYMobileAppRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
  </realm> ?

Comment: Yes.  The app needs to authenticate.  Using com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule means that Worklight will accept any login so long as it includes a user name and password.  But be careful with he security implications