# IBM Mobilefirst Merge 2 Authentication into one

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Currently I am developing for push notification for IOS and Android mobile devices. After sometime of researching I found out that Mobilefirst Push Notification require authentication between server and devices.
[Worklight Push notification in app without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784557/worklight-push-notification-in-app-without-authentication)

Is it possible to merge 2 authentication into 1? Since in my login module, I already have a adapter based authentication. So is there any methods for merging both authentication into 1? I had been googling around yet still kind of can't find a better answer.

Thank You.

Comment: "merge 2 authentication into 1" makes no sense. Please actually explain what does that mean.

Comment: There are two types for Push notification supported by IBM MobileFirst.
1) Eventsource based and 2) Tag based. 1 is tightly coupled with security, 2 is not. 
You have not provided any details at all. Let us know :

a) What is the exact version of your IBM MFP
b) Are you using Eventsource based notifications
c) You mention merging 2 authentication into 1. What are these two?